# How to regularly and incrementally backup photo streams?

Tags: icloud, backup, photos, photo-stream

I have a bunch of photo streams that I share with my wife. I am already using iCloud photos but we would like to backup certain streams regularly to some external media, like SD-cards or hard disks.

Importing all pictures in my photos app and then copying them to the external media is a bit tedious, especially when I am trying to find out which new pictures were added since my last backup.

Are there any tricks, tools or apps that can help me with this task?

Comment: What's wrong with Time Machine?

Comment: I am not sure I could reliably restore from TimeMachine when I accidentally screw up my photo stream. Also, the main problem is syncing the stream with e.g. a local album or folder.

Comment: tbh, I am more inclined to trust my backups than photostream, I'm a bit of a Luddite that way ;)

Comment: Yes, I simply put everything in my iCloud photo library and if I need / want just check the "sync all pictures to this Mac" and have TimeMachine backup everything. However, my wife wants things differently. ;)